# Include file to CGI output using Server Side Includes

Tags: include, cgi, server, ssi

I am trying to include a file using SSI to the output of CGI script. What is the proper way of doing that?
I tried CGI:SSI module with this code and the file wasn’t included.

```
    use CGI::SSI;
    my $ssi = CGI::SSI->new();
    $ssi->include(virtual => 'logo.inc');
```

Or should I use Apache::SSI? If so, what is the simplest way of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the filename/path correct? As stated, if your script is in */cgi-bin/* then your *logo.inc* must also be in */cgi-bin/*. If it can't find the file, it can't include it. You might have meant to write:

```
$ssi->include(virtual => '/logo.inc');
```

if *logo.inc* is in your server's root directory.